# Length for selected options of a select multiple always return 1

Tags: jquery, html

There is a multiple select element :

```
<select id="secta_code" name="secta_code[]" multiple="multiple" size="10"></select>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#secta_code').on('change',function() {
        alert("nb = "+$(this,"option:selected").length);
    });

});
```

How to catch dynamically the number of selected options inside the handler ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternative you can use this:

```js
    $('#secta_code').on('change', function () {
        alert("nb = " + $(":selected", this).length);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="secta_code" name="secta_code[]" multiple="multiple" size="10">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

> The jQuery constructor accepts a 2nd parameter called [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context)  which
>   can be used to override the context of the selection.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method instead:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#secta_code').on('change',function() {
        alert("nb = "+$(this).find("option:selected").length);
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="secta_code" name="secta_code[]" multiple="multiple" size="10">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This time I am obliged to use `find` then :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This :-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#secta_code').on('change',function() {
     alert("nb = "+ $('#secta_code option:selected').length);
  });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f9bgqeqz/)